# Two dimensional array initialization error?

Tags: c++, sdl

```
SDL_Rect *rect = new SDL_Rect[4][2];
```

Error says: "Error: 'this' cannot be used in a constant expression."
Any help??? Happens on the second dimension of the array.

Comment: This, by the way, its a 3 dimensional array. More specifically, a pointer to a 2D array

Comment: I have tried SDL_Rect **rect = ...

Comment: How would i fix it then Dgrinn91???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: that's an odd error message to get for this line

Answer (score 2):

If you know the size of the array, just

```
SDL_Rect rect[4][2];
```

will do what you want.

If you know all dimensions but the first (or if you really need the matrix to be in the heap), you can do

```
SDL_Rect (*rect)[2] = new Rect[x][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

[The correct way to initialize a dynamic pointer to a multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273370/the-correct-way-to-initialize-a-dynamic-pointer-to-a-multidimensional-array)

Initialization of multidimensional arrays is clearly explained.